# How do I install npm version 7.24.2 or lower, on Debian Buster?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, debian-buster

This is on a Raspberry Pi 3, Raspberry Pi OS Lite Legacy (Debian Buster), armv7l. The node version I currently have installed is v10.24.0 (I am trying to run an application that I believe requires node version 10 or lower).

I have git cloned the npm source code from https://github.com/npm/cli, git reset the repository to the commit with tag 7.24.2 and then run `./configure` and `make` successfully. However I'm not sure what to do next to actually install this version. `make install` returns a message saying

> make: Nothing to be done for 'install'.

When I git reset the npm repository back to version 5.8.0 , even `make` failed with

> make: Nothing to be done for 'all'

Is it possible to install npm from source, maybe I am doing a step wrong or missing something? Is there another way to install npm version 7 or lower (even if it also installs node / other packages at the same time)?

(Context: I have to use a program which requires node version of 10 or lower, npm now only supports node 12+)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try installing npm globally?

If not, use this:

```
sudo npm i npm@7.24.0 -g
```

You need to install NPM globally, only then will it reflect the version throughout your system. Also, NPM needs to be installed as a sudo user since you'll be installing it globally and requires admin privileges.